# Folders weight more than files inside (six times)

Tags: file, directory, size, disk, explorer

*This question is not about programming, but about the explorer and files. Just I don't know where else to ask.*

My laptop has two disks, one of them is 1000GB HDD and the other is 256GB SSD. I need to have more place on my SSD than I do now - 256GB'd be enough, but I have some troubles with my folders's weights.

To be more precise, my **"Users"** folder weights **60GB**, both **folders inside** are shown to weight **60GB**, but when I select all the **files** inside the biggest one I see the weight of **11GB**.

I don't know why there is this problem, I didn't find any way to solve in the Internet and here.

Here are the shots: [Users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phzD8.png), [Folders inside "Users"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j8U9.png), [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vduAL.png)

And it is not just a visual bug, I can't put files there since it is full as the explorer [shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNoDe.png).

And, guys, if it is a wrong place to ask such questions, please, tell me the right ones.

Comment: I'd ask on https://superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have some hidden files in your Folder .
To check :
1 - Select View > Options > Change folder and search options.
2 - Select the View tab and, in Advanced settings, select Show hidden files, folders, and drives and OK.

Comment: Man, it IS. Why didn't I think of it...